# Mobile Touch X, Y coordinates not capturing with Android code

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard

I am trying to capture X, Y coordinates for touch event but the output in the CSV is not capturing. I am running this in Android 11 version mobile, but this needs to work Android 9 and above all versions.  Here is the code -

```
    package com.example.kb_keylog;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button startButton, stopButton, submitButton;
    private EditText sentenceEditText;
    private boolean logging = false;
    private int seconds = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private List<String> coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private StringBuilder typedCharacters = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        sentenceEditText = findViewById(R.id.sentenceEditText);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(v -> startLogging());
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(v -> stopLogging());
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(v -> exportToCSV());

        // Add touch listener to capture touch events
        sentenceEditText.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Touch down event
                String touchCoordinates = event.getX() + "," + event.getY();
                String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                coordinatesList.add(timestamp + "," + touchCoordinates + ",TAP");
            }
            return false;
        });

        // Add text change listener to capture typed characters
        sentenceEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Add typed character information
                String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                int endIndex = start + count; // Calculate the end index
                if (count > 0) {
                    // Append typed characters
                    typedCharacters.append(s.subSequence(start, endIndex));
                    coordinatesList.add(timestamp + ",-,-," + s.charAt(endIndex - 1) + "," + typedCharacters.toString() + ",TAP");
                } else {
                    // Backspace/delete key pressed
                    if (start > 0 && typedCharacters.length() > 0) {
                        // Remove the last character from typedCharacters
                        typedCharacters.deleteCharAt(typedCharacters.length() - 1);
                    }
                    coordinatesList.add(timestamp + ",-,-,Backspace," + typedCharacters.toString() + ",Backspace");
                }
            }





            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
    }

    private void startLogging() {
        logging = true;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seconds++;
                startButton.setText("Start (" + seconds + "s)");
                if (logging) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    private void stopLogging() {
        logging = false;
        seconds = 0;
        startButton.setText("Start");
    }

    private void exportToCSV() {
        // Define the content values for the new media file
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "captured_data.csv");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/csv");

        // Prepare the CSV file content
        StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
        csvContent.append("id,xCoordinate,yCoordinate,timestamp,character,charSq,type\n"); // CSV header
        int id = 1;
        for (String entry : coordinatesList) {
            String[] parts = entry.split(",");
            if (parts.length >= 6) { // Ensure array has at least 6 elements
                String timestamp = parts[0];
                String coordinates = parts[1] + "," + parts[2]; // Combine x and y coordinates
                String character = parts[3];
                String charSq = parts[4];
                String type = parts[5];
                csvContent.append(id++).append(",").append(coordinates).append(",").append(timestamp)
                        .append(",").append(character).append(",").append(charSq).append(",").append(type).append("\n");
            } else {
                // Handle invalid entry (missing data)
                // Log a warning or skip this entry
                // You can also consider adding error handling based on your app's requirements
            }
        }

        // Insert the content values into the MediaStore
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);

        try {
            // Open an OutputStream to the MediaStore URI
            OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            if (outputStream != null) {
                // Write data to the OutputStream
                outputStream.write(csvContent.toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.close();

                // Show a success message to the user
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data exported to CSV: " + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any errors that occur during file operations
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error exporting data to CSV", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe on text change or somewhere it is missing to capture the coordinates.